# Why does Apigee Key/Value Map has such format

Tags: key-value, apigee, key-value-store

I'm trying to understand why Apigee has such a format for [Key/Value maps](http://docs.apigee.com/api-reference/content/keyvalue-maps-management-api). When [creating a key](http://docs.apigee.com/management/apis/post/organizations/%7Borg_name%7D/apis/%7Bapi_name%7D/keyvaluemaps) you should POST a JSON like this:

```
{
    "name": "Map_name",
    "entry": [
        {
            "name": "Key1",
            "value": "value_one"
        }, {
            "name": "Key2",
            "value": "value_two"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that `entry` is an array.

When you'r [accessing a Key/Value Map](http://docs.apigee.com/api-services/reference/key-value-map-operations-policy) you should use a policy like this:

```
<KeyValueMapOperations mapIdentifier="Map_name">
    <Scope>environment</Scope>
    <Get assignTo="foo_variable" index="2">
        <Key>
            <Parameter>Key2</Parameter>
        </Key>
    </Get>
</KeyValueMapOperations>
```

As you see, you need to specify both key name and index! Isn't it redundant? Accessing values by index is a bit inconvenient... That's not saying it is 1-based (so Pascal!). Why should I even care about the indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think each key is multi-valued array within the Map. So each key can have more than one values. The array index is for identifying values within the multi-valued key. Not for the entire Map.